# Epub and android. How to get part of html and fit it in webview

Tags: java, android, epub

I am developing a reader and I encountered a problem. I want to open epub files into webview. But I don't know how to get such number of text for fitting in webview as 1 page. I think I need to devide html files from epub. But how ? Help me please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use [epub.js](https://github.com/futurepress/epub.js/blob/master/examples/android-patch.html). It'JS library for epub pagination with TOC and bookmarks.

Comment: Sorry, but I need it on android app